# Kivy ImportError: No module named android.runnable

Tags: android, python, kivy

I was trying kivy google-maps implementation from https://github.com/tito/kivy-gmaps. 
But when I execute main.py, I'm gettting error says

```
ImportError: No module named android.runnable
```

How do I can install the module android.runnable in my Ubuntu 14.04 running Python2.7.6 ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot run this directly on Ubuntu, the android module works only on android - its purpose is to interact with parts of the android api.

Following the other answer, it exists in python-for-android, but only so it can be compiled into apks.

Kivy-gmaps cannot run on anything but android anyway because it works by using a native android maps widget.

Comment: So I can test it on android emulator?

Comment: Probably. Make sure you enable hardware acceleration for kivy to work on it.

Answer (score -2):

You need to install [Python for Android.](http://python-for-android.readthedocs.org/en/latest/android/)

Comment: @Nitheesh If you had it, then the module would be able to import [android.runnable! As you can see, it's in Python for Android.](http://python-for-android.readthedocs.org/en/latest/android/#module-android.runnable)

Comment: I can find a directory in 'python-for-android/build/android/android/android' but not in '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages'. So I copied that folder to system lib. Now another error: " `from android._android import *  
 ImportError: No module named _android `"

Comment: The android module doesn't work on Ubuntu, only on android. I made a full answer about it.